# Why do we have both LVM and an LVM2 tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

These tags don't seem that different. [lvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm) has a tag wiki, whereas [lvm2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm2) does not, leading me to use [lvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm) for my recent LVM2 question. Is there any difference between these, or should one go away? Possibly we could have an [lvm1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm1) tag for anyone who's still using the old version?

Comment: The lvm and lv2 tags have now been merged and lvm2 is a synonym of lvm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't recall seeing a question about LVM1 on this site. It was already obsolete by the time this site started. So for all intents and purposes [lvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm) and [lvm2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm2) are currently equivalent.

I favor merging them, and making [lvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm) the main tag. (Only moderators can do this.)

If an incompatible LVM3 comes along, we can start using [lvm3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm3) for it. Then make [lvm2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm2) the main tag in the [lvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm)/[lvm2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm2) pair and remove the synonym.

Which reminds me, [grub](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grub) is a mess. We have plenty of questions about Grub 1, but Grub 2 questions have also been tagged [grub](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grub), especially as Grub 1 is *now* obsolete.

Comment: Even though grub 1 is obsolete, it will be in production use for a while longer since RHEL5 uses it.

Comment: Just rename everything to grub, the distinction isn't that useful and couldn't be made unambiguously with the existing two tags.

Comment: On the issue of grub, couldn't `grub` just be re-purposed for `grub2` and a `grub1` tag created for the RHEL-based distros? If the feeling is that grub1 shouldn't be expected to be what people are going for as things progress. I think the distinction is very useful since there are important [differences between the two.](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/grub.html#Future)

Comment: @Joel I don't find the split useful for subscription/highlighting purposes, and I wouldn't trust the version if the asker doesn't put it in plain text.

Comment: If [tag:lvm3] arrives, wouldn't [tag:lvm] and [tag:lvm3] need to be synonyms? I'm not sure what one would do in this case. Can you spell it out a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents:

It might create noise, but having `lvm` in the general neighborhood of `lvm2` doesn't really mess things up. There's ambiguity but I don't think it's going to make or break any assumptions people could reasonably be expected to make about the question.

---

If there does need to be a change, from what I can see there are two possibly legitimate uses of the tag:

1) **As a reference to LVM1** as Gilles mentioned. It might be worthwhile to maintain the distinction as someone may have a question about the origins of the current LVM design and referencing a previous iteration might be a good reference point. If LVM2 ever gets marginalized in the enterprise by newer technologies, that would marginalize LVM1 to the point where it's so corner case as to be make this desire moot.

### -----------

2) This is pretty close to how it is now, and I'd prefer it this way: It also may be worthwhile **to reference "Logical Volume Management" as a whole**, which (reading the description) seems like it basically was intended to be and it just wasn't made explicit. This is useful since "LVM" is a pretty broad topic, and providing a catch-all tag for anything under that particular tent may help people attract interested eyeballs to their question. For example, `clvm` could have its own tag as does `lvm2`. If I'm having an issue with clustered LVM, though, `lvm2` feels like the wrong tag to put onto it since my problem isn't related to the particular version of LVM I'm running (except insofar as LVM2 is the only one that supports clustering, which isn't definitional identity since any forthcoming LVM3 would likely have that functionality as well). There's a similar case with HA-LVM.

Also, having a catch-all tag also helps for questions that are likely going to be relevant to all LVM incarnations (such as metadata recovery). Having general questions that are likely to be applicable to people new to the over-all paradigm share a common tag is also useful. For example, if someone is just unfamiliar with the concepts of volume group/physical volume, snapshots, etc.

Almost all my LVM2-related posts are tagged as `lvm` for this reason, I only use `lvm2` if I'm in the mood to be super specific. People are going to assume lvm2 and even if the two were on parity, the onus should be on the asker to clear up ambiguity whether it's this or some other part of their question.

---

Whichever is decided (assuming I'm not overlooking a third option) updating the description to make it explicit is probably still desirable.